# Internal fan controller with specific requirements

Tags: cooling, fan-controller

I'm looking for a fan controller that can do the following/has the following properties:

- Does *not* need a 5.25" or 3.5" slot (preferably thin enough to be hidden in the 15mm space in the back of the case).
- Can control three 3-pin and three 4-pin fans in at least three seperate groups (splitters allowed)
- Can control each group based on at least one 10Ω temperature probe
- Can be programmed via software on the fly (e.g. fan curves)
- Can stop fans completely (0 RPM)

---

I have thus far been using the Corsair Commander Mini, but I've also been continuously dissatisfied with it. It does not meet my last requirement of being able to stop fans, and the state of its firmware and software (Corsair LINK) is horrible (several years long standing bugs still not addressed).

So, does the kind of unit I'm looking for exist?

Comment: have you tried messing around with speedfan yet? I've never had any luck with it but then again I wasn't very dedicated to the concept.

Comment: @AdamWykes Yeah, sadly SpeedFan doesn't seem to detect any of my mainboard fan ports at all :/

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I've also had that issue, you could check your BIOS. But fan "controllability" can vary from BIOS to BIOS.

Comment: @0-60FPS Yeah, the onboard fan controller won't go lower than 40%, I'm also not sure if it can handle fan splitters.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Hmm... I think on board fan power supports 1 amp 12V (12W), usually, you should double check.